# Redirecting http:// and http://www to https://www without affecting other subdomains on the website

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am having two problems with htaccess on my website

1. Redirecting

> http://example.com => https://www.example.com
>
> http://www.example.com => https://www.example.com
>
> https://example.com => https://www.example.com

I have in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

It works well on all browser except when i try accessing example.com on Mozilla Firefox where it rewrites to https://www.example.com/https://example.com/

1. I do not want the htaccess to affect other subdomains on my site. example i do not want 
   http://subdomain.example.com to be redirected.

My website supports wildcard subdomains so I do not rewrite all subdomains.

Comment: The mozilla issue cleared after a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

I have no idea about that mozilla exception you mention. A caching issue maybe? You 'd need to take a closer look at the log files and maybe you have to enable rewrite logging to see what exactly is going on inside the rewriting engine...

Comment: Thanks for your response. It does not redirect http://www.example.com/ to https://www.example.com/ on Google Chrome

Comment: I simplified the rules.